# Build phonegap project to file .apk ready install on devices android

Tags: android, html, cordova

Iam using phonegap to build a game HTML5 for android.

I created phonegap project by commandline: phonegap create myapp.

I test by using app.phonegap.com very ok. game working.

now i want to buil to file .apk to install on my mobile android.

how to process ? Thank all.

Answer (score 0):

This command will compile, and install release version on your device

```
cordova run android -release -device
```

This one, will only compile release version

```
cordova build android -release
```